# Magento2: How do I remove 'My Orders' in Luma sidebar

Tags: magento2, orders, blocks, sidebar

This just suddenly showed up in my left sidebar. It says "My Orders" with a list of past purchases and an "Add to Cart" button. What is this? The block hint is "**Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar**".

I've tried `"referenceBlock name="sidebar.Reorder" remove="true"` in my default.xml but that doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

V 2.0.13 Luma child theme

Comment: please let me know if you have issue.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to keep below code in your default.xml file to remove unnecessary block from sidebar.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="3columns">
        <body>    
            <!-- Compare and wishlist sidebar -->
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
            <!-- Recently order -->
            <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true" />
            <!-- additional sidebar block -->
            <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh! that worked. But only in my vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml. Nothing seems to be registering in the /app/design/frontend/myvendor/myvendor_theme/layout/default.xml. Any idea why? I thought child directories overwrote the base.

Comment: You have to keep default.xml file into app/design/frontend/myvendor/myvendor_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.‌​xml

Answer (score 0):

My Orders is created by the **Magento_Sales** module in *view/frontend/layout/default.xml* by the following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar" name="sale.reorder.sidebar" as="reorder" template="reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The answer @Rakesh posted removes the block but also the parent container, the best way to remove the **My Orders** block is to edit your child themes catalog_category_view.xml. located at *app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>

            <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">

                <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true" />

            </referenceContainer>

        </body>
    </page>
```